# Deleting a foreign key and column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which when I create a definition from SQL Server Management Studio I get this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Settings]
(
    [SettingsID] [int] NOT NULL,    
    [Contact1] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Settings] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SettingsID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Settings] WITH CHECK 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY([Contact1])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserSID])
GO
```

I am trying to remove the `Contact1` column and drop the foreign key

When I try to remove the column directly I get this

```
ALTER TABLE Settings
    DROP COLUMN Contact1
```

Error:

> The object 'FK__GlobalSet_72E607DB' is dependent on column 'Contact1'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 24
>   ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Contact1 failed because one or more objects access this column.

When I try to remove the foreign key first

```
ALTER TABLE Settings
   DROP CONSTRAINT Contact1
```

Error:

> Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
>   'Contact1' is not a constraint.
>   Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 24
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Can someone please tell me how can I delete a column on existing table which is a foreign key.

Thanks

Comment: `FK__GlobalSet_72E607DB`  is the name of the constraint, not `Contact1`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that but was not sure how this is generated..Will this always be same name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945900/dropping-and-recreating-constraints-in-sql-server found this to solve the issue but still not sure how that name was generated.

Comment: Automatically, by SQL Server, because you didn't name the constraint when you produced the foreign key. `ALTER TABLE Settings ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Settings_Contact1_User_UserSID FOREIGN KEY(Contact1) REFERENCES [User](UserSID)` would be the full form. And yes, it's a *really* good idea to do that, because having to get the name at runtime is a pain.

Comment: So I did name it  when adding the column ALTER TABLE Settings
ADD Contact1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,FOREIGN KEY (Contact1) REFERENCES User(UserSID)

Comment: You could just go to the constraint folder for that table, find it and manually delete it.

Comment: No. The *constraint* has no name there, the *column* does. (One column can have multiple foreign key constraints on it, so it can't have a simple name like `Contact1`.) The explicit form of *that* statement is `ALTER TABLE Settings ADD Contact1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, CONSTRAINT FK_Settings_Contact1_User_UserSID FOREIGN KEY(Contact1) REFERENCES dbo.[User](UserSID) `.

Comment: I have to automate a rollback script so can't do it manually..Here is what I noticed even when I name the new foreign key constraint it generates one automatically ..this is a issue since when I move from one server to another this auto generated name will change

Comment: Thanks guys...This works now...Good catch.

Comment: >>>Here is what I noticed even when I name the new foreign key constraint it generates one automatically <<< That is not true, you just did not give it a name. Try this: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Settings]  WITH CHECK ADD constraint FK_Settings_User FOREIGN KEY([Contact1])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserSID]) and FK will have the given name FK_Settings_User

Answer (score 0):

Drop the Constraint 'FK__GlobalSet_72E607DB'